# Heyting algebra in simply typed lambda calculus

Tags: typed-lambda-calculus

The Emil Jeřábek's comment in [Can boolean algebra be expressed in simply typed lambda caclulus?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/10085) give rise to the following question:

Can some non-trivial Heyting algebra be expressed in simply typed lambda calculus?

Consider, for example, the simplest Heyting algebra that is not already a Boolean algebra, that's the totally ordered set $\{0, \frac 12, 1\}$ described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra).

More generally, I ask if is possible to build a type $H$ togheter with two terms $\mathrm{true},\mathrm{false}:H$ and functions $\wedge, \vee, \Rightarrow, \neg:H\to H$ satisfying the inference usual rules for intuitionistic logic, exception for the excluded middle.

Comment: The previous question was about representation of the *specific* 2-element Boolean algebra, not the variety of Boolean algebras. So: *which* Heyting algebra? And what are the conditions that you want the expression to satisfy?

Comment: After the edit: yes, the 2-element Boplean algebra, which is also a Heyting algebra.